# How to add a where clause and / or a order by to a update statement with declare

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently testing using the declare update statement below. This will update my StackCustomerAltID numericly from 1 thourgh 501. But I need to figure out how to add a where clause or a order by using my Customer column in asc order.

here is the where clause I need to add (where DelFlg = 0 and Customer <> 'Spare')

```
declare @Var int
set @Var = 0
update StackCustomer
set @Var = StackCustomerAltID = @Var + 1
```

Comment: Honestly, don't do this. Use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @Larnu how does ROW_NUMBER work, I have never used it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do this. The behaviour is undocumented and *can* give you very odd results. Use `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT StackCustomerAltID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Customer) AS RN
    FROM dbo.StackCustomer)
UPDATE CTE
SET StackCustomerAltID = RN;
```

Comment: That works minus needing to add a where clause to this (where DelFlg = 0 and Customer <> 'Spare')

Comment: Considering that is *completely* omitted from your question, and Mind Reading isn't real, I'm not sure how you expected me, or anyone, to include that in an answer, @JShaffer ...

Comment: I stated needing a where clause and / or a order by in my question, just didn't write out what the where clause need to be.

Comment: So how was I supposed to know what that `WHERE` clause was suppose to be without mind reading, @JShaffer ? Though adding that `WHERE` clause isn't exactly hard. See [WHERE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I am understand what a where clause is just don't know how to add it to your suggested solution.

Comment: No differently to how you normally would, @JShaffer , after the `FROM`.

Comment: follow up question. How would I modifly your answer to order every record in the table, even if the Customer is Blank ? I still need the Customers in ABC order.

Comment: If you have a new question, @JShaffer, post a new question. Though ordering the data in the table makes no sense; they are by design unordered.